# Maven - import / group all modules of project

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a parent project with around 20 child modules:

```xml
<project>
    <modules>
        <module>module-1</module>
        <module>...</module>
        <module>module-20</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

I would like to use this project as one single entity, with all 20 modules included, in other projects. What is the convenient way to do this in Maven?

Should I make a new child module which imports the other 20 modules and refer to this project? Should this be a JAR or a POM project?

```xml
<project>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>... module-1 ...</dependency>
        <dependency>...</dependency>
        <dependency>... module-20 ...</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "as one single entity"?

Comment: @Tunaki I mean that I want to use all 20 child modules. I would like to avoid having to enumerate these 20 child modules over and over again in external projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you mentioned in your question is a good idea. It is actually mentioned as a best practice in the [Maven book](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps), quoting:

> If you have a set of dependencies which are logically grouped together. You can create a project with `pom` packaging that groups dependencies together.

You can create a new module called `module-all`, which would be of `pom` packaging, that simply has a dependency on each of the modules. The packaging should be `pom` because the primary artifact of this module will only be the `pom.xml` (there will be no sources to compile, no JAR...). Then, in your external projects, you can simply add a dependency to this new module (as `<type>pom</type>`) and every `module-i` dependencies will be included transitively.

There would be a cave-at if all of your modules did not share the same version: there would need to be a reference to a specific version of a specific module and you would have to update the `module-all` version each time a module's `version` changes. However, if they all share the same version, `module-all` release cycle would be in line with `module-i`'s.

Comment: Thanks! I read the Maven book, but must have overlooked that. All child modules indeed have the same version in my case, so that will give no problem.